# Can't install with "apt install liblapack* libblas* libopenmpi*"

Tags: apt, software-installation, 20.04

After upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 cannot install lapack, blas, openmpi with apt.

In earlier Ubuntu versions, procedure was simple:

```
apt -y install gfortran
apt -y install build-essential liblapack* libblas*
apt -y install openmpi* libopenmpi*
```

Doing this in 20.04 only gfortran ended successfully.
Let me remind you Sheldon Cooper's "Oh Ubuntu! you are my favorite Linux-based operating system".
So don't lose your reputation among nerds.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What error did you get with the unsuccessful commands? Please [edit] your question to include the output and don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text. Also, you should leave out the text which is not on topic, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-get` instead like:

```
sudo apt-get -y install gfortran
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential "liblapack*" "libblas*"
sudo apt-get -y install "openmpi*" "libopenmpi*"
```